# how to make a email seen unseen in php imap function

Tags: php, mysql, imap, email-client

I am trying to make a php application like email client. when i fetch a mailbox with php imap and read a message then i need to set the email flag as read. but i cannot do that.
I am trying to make a php application like email client. when i fetch a mailbox with php imap and read a message then i need to set the email flag as read. but i cannot do that.

here is some simple code that i use to do it.

```
imap_search($inbox);
imap_delete($inbox,$email_number); 
imap_expunge($inbox);
```

but it will delete the email from mail box.
Now i search the good but not get any proper solution.

Comment: You are aware that there already _are_ a number of free and php based imap clients? Why not use one of them and contribute in case you miss some feature?

Answer (score 1):

your code is used for delete the mail from mail box. you can try this

```
imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');
imap_setflag_full($inbox, $email_number, "\\Seen \\Flagged", ST_UID);
```